# angular2-highcharts: update rendered chart data

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular-promise

I'm trying to render empty chart first and then fill in data. Charts are rendered when the component is initialised and charts are being added through a list of chart options, though empty chart is being rendered successfully, I'm not able to redraw it with updated data. I'm trying to fill in data through service using promise(adding dummy value for reference).

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';

import { configs } from './configs';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
<div *ngFor="let chart of charts">
    <div #chart></div>
</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  charts = [];
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(): void{
      configs.forEach(config => {
          //Add charts
          this.charts.push(config);
      });

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.charts.forEach(chart => {
          chart.series.push({
                          name: 'Installation',
                          data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
          });
      });
  }
}
```

configs.ts

```
    export const configs = [
    {   
        chart:{
            type:'line',
            renderTo: 'line_chart'
        },
        chartName : 'abc',
        title : {text : ''},
        tabHolder : {'id':'line_chart','heading':'Line Chart'},
        xAxis:{categories:[]},
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {enabled: true},
            }
        },
        series: []
    },
    {
        chart:{
            type:'bar',
            renderTo: 'bar_chart'
        },
        chartName : 'xyz',
        title: {text: ''},
        tabHolder : {'id':'bar_chart','heading':'Bar Chart'},
        xAxis: {
            categories: [],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {text: ''},
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    }
]
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts'
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

declare var require: any;
export function highchartsFactory() {
  return require('highcharts');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ChartModule,
  ],
  providers: [{
      provide: HighchartsStatic,
      useFactory: highchartsFactory,
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like angular2-highcharts is just a thin wrapper over Highcharts. The [docs](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#dynamic-interaction-with-chart-object) show how to get the underlying native chart.

Template:

```
<chart [options]="options" 
    (load)="saveInstance($event.context)">
</chart>
```

Component:

```
saveInstance(chartInstance) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
}
```

Since you have an array, you may want to group your initial options with its corresponding native chart.

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of charts">
    <chart [options]="chart.options" 
        (load)="saveInstance($event.context, chart)">
    </chart>
</div>
```

Component:

```
 ngOnInit(): void{
      configs.forEach(config => {
          //Add charts
          this.charts.push({
              options: config,
              nativeChart: null // To be obtained with saveInstance
          });
      });
  }

saveInstance(chartInstance, chart) {
    chart.nativeChart = chartInstance;
}
```

Then use the native API to add your series and redraw:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.charts.forEach(chart => {
        chart.nativeChart.addSeries({
            name: "...",
            data: [...]
        }, true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did try that out, but when we call addSeries method, it gets hold of the chart added to charts(list) not the rendered chart. We need to somehow manipulate already added chart in DOM.

Comment: Check out my update. The docs show how to get the underlying chart.